# sorting primefaces 4.0 didn't working

Tags: java, primefaces

i want to sort datatable in primefaces 4.0 but it didn't working. Here's my datatable

```
<p:dataTable value="#{transactionReportBacking.transaction}"
                             var="trx"
                             lazy="true"
                             rows="20"
                             paginator="true"
                             paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                             styleClass="table table-hover table-striped"
                             id="tableTransaction">
                    <p:columnGroup type="header">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column headerText="Customer ID" sortBy="customerId"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Nama Customer"/>
                            <!--<p:column headerText="Area" />-->
                            <p:column headerText="Jumlah Dibayar"/>                   
                            <p:column headerText="Nama Collector" />
                            <p:column headerText="Waktu Transaksi"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Tanggal Janji Bayar"/>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:columnGroup>
                    <p:column >
                        <h:outputText value="#{trx.customerId}" styleClass="numeric-value"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column sortBy="customerName">
                        <h:outputText value="#{trx.customerName}" />
                    </p:column><p:column style="text-align: right" sortBy="amount">
                        <h:outputText value="#{trx.amount}" style="display: inline-block; text-align: right">Rp. 
                            <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###.##" />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column> 
                    <p:column sortBy="collector.name">
                        <h:outputText value="#{trx.collector.name}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column sortBy="transactionTimestamp">                                
                        <h:outputText value="#{trx.transactionTimestamp}" styleClass="numeric-value">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" timeZone="GMT+7"/>
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column sortBy="promisedDate">
                        <h:outputText value="#{trx.promisedDate}" styleClass="numeric-value">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" timeZone="GMT+7"/>
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

you will see `<p:column headerText="Customer ID" sortBy="customerId"/>` i can click on Customer ID column but, there's nothing change. Any response would be apreciate, and sorry for my bad english. Oh i'm using lazydatamodel and pagination

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the column with the `headerText` just one time instead of making that columngroup for the headers?

You should be able to make your column sortable with the following:

```
<p:column headerText="Customer ID" sortBy="customerId">
    <h:outputText value="#{trx.customerId}" styleClass="numeric-value"/>
</p:column>
```

Comment: there's a problem in css, so i must create column group